# Forcing nice positions of summation Σ 's under and overscript in FractionBox

Tags: output-formatting, summation, display, subscript

Apologies if this has been asked before.

The expression

```
expr = Defer @ Sum[
 FractionBox[
   z^p
   , p!
   ] FractionBox[
   Sum[k^(p + s), {k, 1, n}]
   , Binomial[p + s, p]
   ]
 , {p, 0, Infinity}
 ]
```

[image]

produces

```
expr //DisplayForm //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

using `DisplayFrom` and `TraditionalForm` (in combination with `Defer` and `HoldForm`).
Is there a way to force *Mathematica* to display the second sum in the numerator nicely, similarly to the first sum (i.e. underscript under and on top of the summation).

Thank you for all help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [`LimitsPositioning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LimitsPositioning) suboption to [`UnderoverscriptBoxOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnderoverscriptBoxOptions). For example:

```
expr = Defer @ Sum[
    Defer[z^p/p!] Defer[Sum[k^(p+s),{k,1,n}]/Binomial[p+s,p]],
    {p, 0, Infinity}
];

expr //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Using the [`LimitsPositioning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LimitsPositioning) option:

```
Style[expr, UnderoverscriptBoxOptions -> {LimitsPositioning -> False}] //TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Carl, that's exactly what I was looking for. Works fine. Much appreciated.